What is the use of the given circuit identity?
In Exercise 4.20 in Nielsen & Chuang we are asked to prove the circuit identity $(H_1 \otimes H_2) CX_{1,2}(H_1 \otimes H_2) = CX_{2,1}$

which is done technically by definition.
As a followup, it is then requested to show, using this identity the effect of CNOT on $|\pm\rangle  |\pm\rangle$ and that in this case the control and target roles are swapped.
Please help me understand how is the above identity helps in doing so?

I think one of your $CX$ should have the control and targets reversed, in your equation. The image is correct

@JahanClaes Why is that? From what i understand, in the left circuit the first qubit is the control and the second is the target and therefore its a $CX_{1,2}$. In the right circuit, the first qubit is the target and the second is the control and therefore its a $CX_{2,1}$.

the original post had $CX_{1,2}$ on both sides of the equation, but since I made my comment my edit was approved that fixed it

It's a little annoying to apply CNOT to $|\pm\rangle|\pm\rangle$, since CNOT is defined in the $Z$ basis. But, we know that $\text{CX}_{12}=H_1H_2 \text{CX}_{21}H_1H_2$ (Here, $\text{CX}_{ij}$ denotes a CNOT with control $i$ and target $j$). So we have, e.g.,
\begin{equation}
\text{CX}_{12}|+\rangle|+\rangle = H_1H_2 \text{CX}_{21}H_1H_2|+\rangle|+\rangle=H_1H_2\text{CX}_{21}|0\rangle|0\rangle=H_1H_2|0\rangle|0\rangle=|+\rangle|+\rangle
\end{equation}
You can do the same for all other states in the $X$ basis. The point is the Hadamards transform the $X$ basis (annoying) into the $Z$ basis (easy), letting you find the action of the CNOT relatively simply.
Of course, you could also write $|+\rangle|+\rangle = \frac{1}{2}\left[|0\rangle|0\rangle+|0\rangle|1\rangle+|1\rangle|0\rangle+|1\rangle|1\rangle\right]$ and apply $\text{CX}_{12}$ directly to get the same answer.

Great, thank you!
